# Howto re-attach subclipse when using a new Eclipse on an existing workspace

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I have some projects in a workspace that were imported from SVN using Subclipse. Now I'm opening this workspace with a new version of Eclipse (with Subclipse) and the "Team" context menu only contains "Apply patch".

Is there a way of getting subclipse working with these projects without having remove them from the workspace, and do a new import from SVN?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273548/associating-existing-eclipse-project-with-existing-svn-repository which contains the answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Maybe you do not have disconnected your projects before uninstalling the previous SVN Team Provider.
So all projects are still connected to the removed older version of the plug-in.
In that case Team Services does not show "Share Project" menu item.

The only way to reconnect these projects would be to remove them from workspace (without content deletion) then re-import these projects into workspace: pure eclipse operation: no SVN re-import needed.

See also [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.technology.subversive/msg00490.html).

Comment: Can also use the ill-named command "team -> share", cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273548/associating-existing-eclipse-project-with-existing-svn-repository

Answer (score 13):

If you've forgotten to "Disconnect" a project before switching plugins or Eclipse versions, you can clean it up by deleting some index files from your workspace.

Assuming you're on a 'nix-based OS shutdown Eclipse then:

```
cd $WORKSPACE
find .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects -name 'properties.index' -delete
```

Re-launch Eclipse, and you should be able to do Share Project again.  The same works if you try to switch from Subversive to Subclipse and find yourself with only an Apply Patch option and no Share Project under the Team menu.

Solution oringinally found here: http://mschrag.blogspot.com/2010/11/switching-from-subversive-back-to.html

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but when I update subclipse to last version the problem came out for me.
http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar situation.
I had made some changes in a project that I got from SVN, for some reason it disconnected from the SVN and the only option in the menu was "Apply Path". :P

What I did?

I made a copy of the project.
Deleted the project from eclipse (with content deletion), so the project from workspace gone.
I created a new project from SVN, then I copied the backup project folder and pasted in the new folder project from SVN and it works fine, it showed the changes I've made.
:)

Hope its help some one.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all the `'CVS'` folders from the local copy, with the workspace of the project. Now, refresh the project in eclipse view. Do a new import form `SVN` . `Team > share project`

Answer (score 0):

Removing and importing project again is the way but not always convenient (run configurations and breakpoints are lost when project is deleted from workspace)

Pendors hints ([look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6529134/1948151)) allowed me to re-attach Sublipse to existing project in my Eclipse workspace without reimporting project.

For Windows users: Just find and delete properties.index in
    EclipseWorkspaceFolder.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.projects\YourProjectName\.indexes

In Eclipse, right click on YourProject leaf in Package Explorer, select Team->Share Project and follow ShareProject wizard. Worked for me! Thanks.