# subclipse not showing "share project" option on project context menu in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

Within eclipse, with Subclipse installed, if I right click a project and select "team" there are normally 2 options:

- apply patch
- share project

Once you have shared project you get the full Subclipse menu from "team"

One project however only has one option - apply patch. If I close the project I see both options but the share project option is grayed out.

I have other projects where this is not happening.

What could be special about this project to stop me getting the share project option? Is there another path to the share project function I could use?

Regards

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?  I am having the same problem.

Comment: I've found this question and answer relevant to Git projects in Eclipse (with EGit)

Answer (score 54):

Solve this problem with these steps:

- Verify that you can update using TortoiseSVN (this will guarantee that your .svn is not corrupt)
- Delete all your projects that have this problem, but in the delete dialog, **do not delete the project contents!**
- Select File -> Import -> Existing projects into Workspace.
- Select your projects folder or your workspace folder.

Subeclipse should now detect and connect your projects automatically, without need to select 'Share Project' for each one of them.

Comment: Perfect.  I had the infamous JavaHL issues, and couldn't find another way for Subclipse to "Try again".

Comment: Still working with Eclipse Luna. Really, the Subclipse guys ought to provide a "rescan project" option - or if there already is one, mark it more clearly. I could find no other way, and I *have* looked.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me! In my case my eclipse projects stopped showing svn options after chaning my subclipse to subversive. And then it started working after deleting, importing project again!

Comment: Awesome. Now my project is grayed out and I can't import it again.

Comment: This worked for me with Eclipse 2022-09 and Subclipse 4.3.3

Answer (score 3):

This is usually the case when the directory containing the project is not properly under version control (bad or corrupted `.svn`).

So:

- can you execute SVN commands in a shell a the root of your project?
- where are your `.project` and `.classpath` files (in the eclipse workspace or at the root directory of your project?)

Answer (score 3):

If you upgraded your Eclipse recently, make sure you're still using the same SVN plugins... :)

In my case, I upgraded my Eclipse and **accidentally installed Subversive instead of Subclipse**. The existing .svn directory of the project contained data in the format expected by Subclipse, and so Subversive got confused (e.g. but not showing the "Share Project" option).

Comment: Thanks a lot for adding your valuable comment. It saved my time.

Answer (score 3):

Close Project and Re-Open project has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem after emergency-migrating (again!) from Subversive to Subclipse.
Old .svn entries are all there but Subclipse won't pick them up.

I can successfully commit using an external tool, in this case TortoiseSVN, but in Eclipse, I just see normal Java projects that cannot be shared (because of stale .svn entries I suspect).

The only solution I see is to commit everything you want to keep with an external tool, then freshly check out your projects into a new workspace and copy over any missing pieces from your old workspace.

Answer (score 1):

Try to select prespective as java instead of j2ee and then restart as eclipse .

This works for me.

Comment: Thats the correct answear

Answer (score 1):

Delete the file:

`<ECLIPSE_WS>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\<PROJECT_NAME>\.indexes\properties.index`

And the Share Project option appears!

Comment: This worked for me like a charm... I probably used different svn plugin before upgrade to current eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly same situation with Yaniv above.

> If you upgraded your Eclipse recently, make sure you're still using
>   the same SVN plugins... :)
>
> In my case, I upgraded my Eclipse and accidentally installed
>   Subversive instead of Subclipse. The existing .svn directory of the
>   project contained data in the format expected by Subclipse, and so
>   Subversive got confused (e.g. but not showing the "Share Project"
>   option).

My solution is like below:

1. Exported the current project in the new workspace into .war file.
2. Double-checked the current project is in the svn repository.
3. Removed the project in the new workspace completely once I was sure that I have the exported .war file and svn repository so that I will be able to import the project again.
4. Imported the project from svn, and checked out the project from the svn.
   (Or, you can import the project from the .war file and you will be able to Share Project)

-> It worked well with the Subversive which is installed in the new workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Please double check if you were using: **Subversive** or **Subclipse**?

It is likely that you have opened an old project with a newer Eclipse installation, where the software to be used may not be the one used previously, for example:

- Subclipse instead of Subversive
- Subversive instead of Subclipse

In my case after a fresh install of "Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers"
Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)
Build id: 20180917-1800
while I needed to make some modifications to an ancient SVN tracked project.

I had Subclipse instead of Subversive (so simple yet you may be up for a spin).
Credit to the answer from Yaniv, he had installed the software the other way around - same issue.