# Telling Eclipse a project is already under Git version control

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

If I have a project in Eclipse checked out with `git clone` (or created with `git init`), but not through `Import > Git > Projects from Git`, is it possible to tell Eclipse about it without deleting/moving the project and checking it out again?

Comment: Contextual menu, Team, Share Project... doesn't do it?

Comment: in netbeans, opening the project as a "project with existing sources" work. Isn't it the same in Eclipse ?

Comment: @pedromarce And set the repository to the directory where the project is?

Comment: yes, something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194877/how-make-eclipse-egit-recognize-existing-repository-information-after-update

Comment: @pedromarce Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted. Unfortunately, it didn't show up in "related questions" or I missed it.