# How to include a forked repo from Git into my eclipse java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github

I am working on a forked repository and want to include that into my local Eclipse project. I have gone through many documents over the internet and I am unable to find any relevant document. Whatever I do, I end up copying file with no .project file in the eclipse project folder and hence is unable to debug that. Please help if any one doing the same. Its surprising not to find anything on net. May be I am missing something. Any pointers to such document will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A forked repo (meaning a [clone of a repo on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6286877/6309)) is like any other repo.
You can clone it locally, and if that repo include a `.project` and a `.classpath`, import that project into your Eclipse workspace.

Then, you can add that existing local repo (that you have cloned locally) in your Eclipse Git repository view: see "[How make Eclipse/EGit recognize existing repository information after update?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7194878/6309)".

Or you can import the git repo in your Eclipse Git view following:

- "[Starting from existing Git Repositories](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Starting_from_existing_Git_Repositories) "
- "[Import projects directly from Github](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html#github_mylynprojects)" (if your fork is initially on GitHub)

But remember: if the repo hasn't versioned the `.project` and a `.classpath`, no amount of fork or clone will make it easier to import as a project in your Eclipse.