# Egit: Right click not showing GIT commands

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I can't see the GIT commands when using right click on any files in a GIT repository.

I'm using Eclipse-Luna, A fresh install, afeter trying different versions of EGIT.

Thanks,
Elyahu

Some screen shots of the preferences:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't see the GIT commands when using right click on any files in a GIT repository.

You must first share that local project in order to make it recognized as a Git repository.
See "[How make Eclipse/EGit recognize existing repository information after update?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7194878/6309)",but don't forget, once shared, to close/reopen your project.
Then Git will be active on said project.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I must add @NickKlauer comment on the link you specified: "This is ridiculous. The fact that I had to Google to find this solution is sad. I'm surprised Eclipse doesn't just turn it on for projects with a .git directory. Thanks for asking this and finding a solution, as I've been banging my head against a wall for a while on this problem... – Nick Klauer"