# eclipse svn "The working copy needs to be upgraded"

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I've just upgraded to Eclipse Luna on a laptop that I don't use much. I'm trying to get my projects in sync with my svn server (hosted), but am running into the "The working copy needs to be upgraded" message.
I do not have a local svn client; I only use Subversive in Eclipse. I've upgraded all the plugins. What's next?

```
Some resources were not updated.
The working copy needs to be upgraded
svn: The working copy at '[my directory]'
is too old (format 10) to work with client version '1.8.10 (r1615264)' (expects format 31). You need to upgrade the working copy first.
```

Comment: I had a similar error because I copied a project folder from another PC (and it contained some .svn folders). I fixed the problem using http://stackoverflow.com/a/12399419/3885376 - I deleted all .svn folders and then add + commit worked.

Answer (score 8):

Does this help?
[SVN upgrade working copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992034/svn-upgrade-working-copy)

> With the command line client, you have to manually upgrade your working copy format by issuing the command `svn upgrade`

Or:

> from eclipse, you can select on the project, right click->team->upgrade

Comment: + from eclipse, you can select on the project, right click->team->upgrade

Comment: Tried that, but what i see is a disabled "Upgrade Projects" menu item.

Comment: And I've made sure that everything is upgraded as well, though I'm not sure how to tell what version of the client I'm using.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767144/subclipse-not-showing-share-project-option-on-project-context-menu-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Using TortoiseSVN perform a "cleanup" and check the "Break Locks" option. After this happened to me twice in the last year, I figured this out. Works perfectly.