# Importing in Eclipse an existing SVN checkout

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-cdt

I have made an SVN checkout (using Tortoise SVN). Then imported it in Eclipse workspace (placed in a different directory) as `Makefile Project with Existing Code`. This seemed to work fine.

But it appears that Eclipse doesn't see that this is an SVN checkout. I don't see any way of for example looking at local changes to a file or its history.

Yet I do have SVN plugins in Eclipse. In particular I can browse the SVN repository without a problem.

How to tell Eclipse to work with existing checkout? Is that possible?

If not I could consider checking out from within Eclipse (but will I still be able to use that checkout with Tortoise SVN?). But how to make it to external directory (not a subdirectory of workspace)? How then to make Eclipse interpret it as `Makefile Project with Existing Code`?

---

**Update**:

I have following software installed within Eclipse:

- Collaboration

  - Subversive SVN Integration for the Mylyn Project (Optional) 1.1.0.I20130527-1700
  - Subversive SVN JDT Ignore Extensions (Optional) 1.1.0.I20130527-1700
  - Subversive SVN Team Provider 1.1.0.I20130527-1700
  - Subversive SVN Team Provider Localization (Optional) 1.1.0.I20130527-1700
  - Subversive SVN Team Provider Sources 1.1.0.I20130527-1700
- Subversive SVN Connectors

  - Subversive SVN Connectors 3.0.1.I20130507-1700
  - SVNKit 1.7.9 Implementation (Optional) 3.0.1.I20130507-1700

And from Eclipse Marketplace:

- Subversive - SVN Team Provider

In Preferences/Team/SVN/SVN Connector I can chose one of:

- Native JavaHL 1.7.9 r1462340 (SVN 1.7.9)
- SVNKit 1.7.9 r9659_v20130411_2103 (SVN 1.7.9 compatible, all platforms)

Tortoise SVN is in version 1.8.1, Build 24570, 64bit (Eclipse is 32).

Comment: If eclipse doesn't recognize the SVN connection you are missing one of subclipse or subversive plug-in in eclipse. With one of these installed you can also check out from eclipse. And yes TortoiseSVN will be able to commit if you check out with eclipse.

Comment: @user714965 I have updated the question with more details on what I have installed. What am I missing then?

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273548/associating-existing-eclipse-project-with-existing-svn-repository?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

A few notes that might help:

1. Looks like your Tortoise SVN is 1.8.x, but your Eclipse plugins are 1.7.x.  SVNKit website does state that 1.7.x SVNKit will not read 1.8.x SVN trees.  Generally speaking, I think it is best for the SVNKit version to match your SVN version.
2. A beta version of SVNKit 1.8.x is available if you would like to try it:  http://svnkit.com/download.php.
3. Eclipse has always been finicky for me with regards to upgrading modules and retroactive source base detection.  When I upgraded from SVN 1.6 to 1.7, I had to delete my project from Eclipse and re-import it in order to get Eclipse to start displaying the "Team" menu options again.